# Updating Dynamic Factor Model within a time-period

Tags: factor-analysis, kalman-filter

I have the following question.

Assume that we have the standard Dynamic Factor Model:
$$
X_{i,q} = \beta_i F_q + \epsilon_{i,q}, \qquad \epsilon_{i,q} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_i^2),
$$
and
$$
F_q = \phi_f F_{q-1} + u_q, \qquad u_q \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_F^2),
$$
where $i \in (1, \ldots, I)$ is the number of firms and $q \in (1, \ldots, Q)$ is the number of time periods.

The data is at the quarterly level and the model could be estimated using the standard techniques. Now, let's assume that we have a new quarter $Q+1$ and the data ($X_{1,Q+1}, \ldots, X_{j,Q+1}$) starts to realize. If we wait till the end of the quarter, we can re-estimate the model to obtain $F_{Q+1}$. However, I'm interested in the changes in the conditional expectation of $F_{Q+1}$ through the quarter, e.g. after first 5 days. Namely $p(F_{Q+1}|D_{Q+1,5})$, where I denote $D_{q,t}$ as the information after $t$ days in quarter $q$. I think that it will be
$$
p(F_{Q+1}|D_{Q+1,5}) \propto p(D_{Q+1,5}|F_{Q+1}) p(F_{Q+1}),
$$
where $p(F_{Q+1}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\phi_f F_{q-1}, \sigma_F^2)$ given the law of motion for the latent factor and $p(D_{Q+1,5}|F_{Q+1})$ follows from the observation equation and given $\beta_i$ and $\sigma_i$ equivalent to the likelihood in the linear regression setting.

For simplicity, I assume here that we do not update the beliefs about all other parameter (e.g. $\beta_i$) during the quarter and take them as given (of course taking into account uncertainty). We will update the beliefs about all the model parameters after the end of quarter $Q+1$.

The question is, whether the logic that I outlined above is correct. Thank you in advance!